# Click on Google Map Marker, load wordpress post into div

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps

I'm working on a Wordpress site with a google map as the main page. The markers on the map are created by the posts, which each have a location associated with them (by using Advanced Custom Fields). My goal is to click on any particular marker, and have it load that marker's associated post into a div at the bottom of the screen.

```
<div class="acf-map">
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ($query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            <?php 

            $location = get_field('location');

            if( !empty($location) ):
            ?>

                <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>"></div>

            <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

The divs with class "marker" are not actually loaded onto the map directly, but rather they are collected from a script and passed with the following function to a google method

```
function add_marker( $marker, map ) {

    // var
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng'))

    var postid = $marker.attr('id');

    // create marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position    : latlng,
        map         : map,
        idofpost    : postid
    });

    // add to array
    map.markers.push( marker );
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content:"<?php the_field('sound_description'); ?>"
    });

  $.each()
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

As a beginner, I'm having difficulty figuring out the best workflow to achieve my above-stated goal. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Just store the post id on the marker, so you can use it to retrieve the post.

Comment: Musa, thank you, however the divs don't actually get placed within the map. There's a javascript call that fetches the divs (with class "marker") and stores them into an array which passes the code to google map's object literal for creating maps.